# Bash Script if condition is always true

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to create a event handler for icing. My Bash script looks like this right now:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Event Handler for loggin out inactive RDP users

# $1 is $SERVICESTATE$ (OK WARNING UNKNOWN CRITICAL)
# $2 is $SERVICESTATETYPE$ (SOFT HARD)
# $3 is $SERVICEATTEMPT$ (1 through 4)
# $4 is $SERVICDOWNTIME$ (0 no Downtime, >0 Downtime active)
# $5 is SRV29 
# $6 is $host.name$ (1 through 4)


if  [ "$4" > 0 ];
 echo "in downtime, exit";
 then exit
fi

case "$1" in
OK)
echo "ok!"
;;
WARNING)
echo "warning!"
;;
UNKNOWN)
echo "unknown!"
;;
CRITICAL)
echo "critical!"
...
```

When I execute this script without my if statement at the top, everything works fine. But I want to check if $4 is greater than 0. This test condition always returns true and no matter what I enter inside this condition it always results in "in downtime, exit".

So even `if [ "hello" = "hallo" ]` it will go inside and exit right away.
I also tried pretty much every variation with quotes, without, double brackets... and so on.
I am obviously doing something wrong. Can anyone spot it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use `>` inside `[...]`, it means redirection there. In some shells, you can use `\>`, or better to use standard one `-gt`.

Comment: @cuonglm thanks, didn't actually know! But I also tried -gt which still results in the same beaviour

Comment: You stated that `# $4 is $SERVICDOWNTIME$ (1 through 4)`, so it's always true, isn't it?

Comment: @cuonglm this is a copy & paste error I made. it actually is 0 when no downtime is active. Also, right now I still execute the script by hand so the var does not get polled for this test

Comment: Please fix the `if` statement's syntax first. the `then` must be attached like as: `if [ "$4" -gt 4 ]; then`

Comment: @RakeshSharma yes, you were right, too. thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For testing integers you will want to use:

```
-eq  #Is equal
-ne  #Is not equal
-lt  #Less than
-le  #Less than or equal
-gt  #Greater than
-ge  #Greater than or equal
```

So your `test` statement should read:

```
if  [ "$4" -gt 0 ];
```

Additionally, your `if` statement is missing the `then` so it should be corrected to:

```
if  [ "$4" -gt 0 ]; then
```

See `man test` for more `test` options.

Comment: I'd add that the `>` is probably redirecting output and creating a file called `0` in the current directory.

Comment: @Wolf480pl yes you are right. @Timothy: I still get the same behavior with `-gt`.. my echo gets displayed and the script exits

Comment: For debugging you can temporarily add a flag to the first line of your script.  `#!/bin/bash -x` may help you to see what is actually happening and where the failure is.

Comment: i removed my echo inside the if statement. now it works. Seems that the syntax has to be `if [ "$4" -gt 0 ]; then` which would mean that I can not put an echo inside.. (right?)

Comment: You can put an `echo` inside an `if` block.  The `then` needs to be first.

Comment: @TimothyMartin ah man that was a uber Friday brain fart haha. of course that works like that. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

Your `if` statement is all whacked off.

```
if [ "$4" -gt 0 ]; then
   # stuff to do when $4 > 0
else
   # stuff to do when $4 <= 0
fi
```

Comment: @jlliagre Yes you are right on both counts. Regarding quoting the 0, they are a result of involuntary quoting of shell commands!.

Comment: FWIW, in American English "whacked off" means something other than "malformed". :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if  [ ... ];
    echo "in downtime, exit";
    then exit
fi
```

As the other answers mention, the `then` keyword is in the wrong place in this `if` condition. (It's not missing, from the point of view of the shell language. If it were, that would be a syntax error.)

What happens here, is that *both* commands before the `then` are taken as part of the condition, and the return value of the whole lot is used to choose if the part after `then` runs. With commands separated by semicolons, only the exit status of the last command matters.

Since `echo` will probably always succeed, the conditional branch always runs. Something like `if true; false; then echo something; fi` would never run the `echo` though. I would suggest putting the `then` keyword on the same line as the condition, to avoid accidentally adding something between them.

With `if`, using multiple commands in the condition is likely to be just confusing, but with `while` it might have it's uses: we could have something like this:

```
while value=$(somecommand) ; [ "$value" != 0 ] ; do
    echo "do some work with $value"
done
```

Both the assignment and test run on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I think now I understand what went wrong here.