# While loop for checking active processes fails

Tags: bash, shell-script, ps

I created a shell script which I am running using nohup. This script runs various sql script in sequence but few in parallel also. I have the following statements in my script-

```
echo exit | sqlplus -s ${username}/${pwd}@${DB} @close1.sql
echo exit | sqlplus -s ${username}/${pwd}@${DB} @close2.sql

echo exit | sqlplus -s ${username}/${pwd}@${DB} @insertPricing1.sql &
pid1=$!
echo exit | sqlplus -s ${username}/${pwd}@${DB} @insertPricing2.sql &
pid2=$!

echo "Pricing Insert PIDs => ${pid1}, ${pid2}"

while [ `ps -p ${pid1},${pid2} | wc -l` > 1 ]
do
sleep 5
done

echo exit | sqlplus -s ${username}/${pwd}@${DB} @insertPricing3.sql
```

The intention is to run close1 -> close2 -> insertPricing1 & insertingPricing2 in parallel -> insertPricing3. where -> means in sequence.

When I checked the result the next day (after sufficient time it should have been completed), I saw that the shell script was still running. Pricing1 and Pricing2 were done but Pricing3 didn't start. The processes for 1 and 2 had finished.

## ps -p 19105,19107

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
```

There is some problem in the while loop as when I run this in

```
 # ps -p 19105,19107 | wc -l
1
```

but this-

```
# while [ `ps -p 19105,19107 | wc -l` > 1 ]
> do
> echo "hello"
> done
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
........ ctrl+C
```

so why this loop works when 1 is not greater than 1? What should be the solution?

Comment: See [Bash Script if condition is always true](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/353633/65304)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @steeldriver's comment for helping me out. It was a silly mistake from my side. > is considered as redirection operator inside [ ] (or most of the places in a shell script). The standard way to use is `-gt`

For comparing integers as per the answer in the link-

```
-eq  #Is equal
-ne  #Is not equal
-lt  #Less than
-le  #Less than or equal
-gt  #Greater than
-ge  #Greater than or equal
```

Comment: You can use `>` for comparison, but for string comparison, and it has to be escaped like `\>`.